# What is the proper way to allow arguments to pass via ... through multiple functions with purrr map

Tags: r, parameter-passing, purrr

Consider the following three functions:

```
f1 <- function(df, ...) {
  df %>%
    mutate(
      model = map(.$splits, ~ f2(.))
    )
}

f2 <- function(split_df) {
  split_df %>%
    analysis() %>% 
    nest() %>%
    mutate(
      forecast = map(data, ~ f3(.$actuals))
    )
}

f3 <- function(x, N = 3, fn = mean, window_size = 6, ...) {
  # stuff
}
```

I am running these functions in a larger pipeline, but the gist of my question is this: I would like to pass arguments to `f3()` (e.g. change `fn = mean` to `fn = median` in the following line of code:

```
df_resamples %>%
  mutate(
    result = .$resamples %>% map(~ f1(.))
  )
```

However, neither of the following return the the correct results:

```
# INCORRECT
df_resamples %>%
  mutate(
    result = .$resamples %>% map(~ f1(.), fn = median)
  )
# ALSO INCORRECT
df_resamples %>%
  mutate(
    result = .$resamples %>% map(~ f1(., fn = median))
  )
```

If I hardcode `fn` in `f2` I get the correct result:

```
f2_good <- function(split_df) {
  split_df %>%
    analysis() %>% 
    nest() %>%
    mutate(
      forecast = map(data, ~ f3(.$actuals, fn = median))
    )
}
```

### How come I cannot pass `fn = median` through to `f3` if I am passing `...` from `f1`?

*NOTE: I am able to solve passing the arguments through to `f1` and `f2` but this does not feel very DRY and I thought I could use the ellipsis to circumvent this approach:*

```
f1 <- function(df, N = 3, fn = mean, window_size = 6) {
  df %>%
    mutate(
      model = map(.$splits, ~ f2(., N = N, fn = fn, window_size = window_size))
    )
}

f2 <- function(split_df, N = 3, fn = mean, window_size = 6) {
  split_df %>%
    analysis() %>% 
    nest() %>%
    mutate(
      forecast = map(data, ~ f3(.$actuals, N = N, fn = fn, window_size = window_size))
    )
}
```

Doing the above, enables me to do:

```
df_resamples %>%
  mutate(
    result = .$resamples %>% map(~ f1(., fn = median))
  )
```

and get the expected results, but I have to pass the default values through to both `f1` and `f2`...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `...` to each signature and function call, like:

```
f1 <- function(df, ...) {
  df %>%
    mutate(
      model = map(.$splits, ~ f2(., ...))
    )
}

f2 <- function(split_df, ...) {
  split_df %>%
    analysis() %>% 
    nest() %>%
    mutate(
      forecast = map(data, ~ f3(.$actuals, ...))
    )
}

f3 <- function(x, N = 3, fn = mean, window_size = 6, ...) {
  # stuff
}
```

and then call

```
df_resamples %>%
  mutate(
    result = .$resamples %>% map(~ f1(., fn = median))
  )
```

*EDIT: Toy-Example*

```
f1 <- function(x, ...) f2(x, ...)
f2 <- function(x, ...) f3(x, ...)
f3 <- function(x, fn = mean, na.rm = FALSE, ...) fn(x, na.rm = na.rm) 

f1(c(1,2,3,NA), fn = max, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Yes, but that fails with a weird error -- see my edit above about a solution that works, but does not feel very DRY.

Comment: My advice was passing the `...` from `f1` down to `f3`. Hence changing `map(.$splits, ~ f2(.))` to `map(.$splits, ~ f2(., ...)`, `f2 <- function(split_df)` to `f2 <- function(split_df, ...)` and `map(data, ~ f3(.$actuals))` to `map(data, ~ f3(.$actuals, ...))`. Can you send me the error if it does not work?

Comment: I get what you're doing, it was one of the first alternatives that I tried, but it ends up creating an error with the `f3` function: ` Error in (n + 1):(n + N) : NA/NaN argument` -- doing a traceback / debug, it looks like, for some reason when attempting this approach, a `data.frame / tibble` is being passed to `f3` rather than a vector that would be expected via `.$actuals`.